# Beltrami Laplace Operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, compact-operators

In the proof of Theorem 1.6.1 of Tromba's  [Teichmüller Theory in Riemannian geometry](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-0348-8613-0), it says:

> For $(M,g)$ a closed Riemann Surface of genus $g\ge 2$, the Fredholm alternative holds for the operator 
>   $$\Delta_g-id:H^s(M,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow H^{s-2}(M,\mathbb{R}).$$

And then the author goes on in showing its injectivity.

Similarly, in another paper but in the same setting, I have the operator
$$\delta_g\delta_g^\ast:\mathfrak{X}_s(M)\rightarrow \mathfrak{X}_{s-2}(M),$$
$\mathfrak{X}_s(M)$ being $H^s$ vector fields, and again the author states that it has trivial kernel (which is easy to show) - and thus I assume that its surjectivity follows as above.

I am quite new to the subject, so I was wondering if you could explain why the Fredholm alternative applies to these particular operators, or provide a reference for this kind of problems.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not $\Delta$ which is compact but  the map $I_u:H^1\rightarrow (H^1)^*$ given by 
$$I_u(v): v\mapsto \int_M uv d\mu$$

Tromba refers to Gilbarg and Trudinger, Elliptic Partial Differential Equations (2nd edition) - the relevant Theorem is Theorem 8.3 in that book. There you will find a similar result for elliptic boundary value problems of second order (for the case $s=0$). The basic reasoning in your situation is the same, however. The compactness of the aforementioned map is Lemma 8.5 in that book, the Fredholm alternative for bilinear forms applied to elliptic partial differential equations is Theorem 8.6.

Since all arguments involve only estimates for integrals they carry over more or less directly to the case of compact surfaces.

Comment: First off, thank you for you answer. Funny enough, I was already looking at that exact part when posing the question. The problem is, that it seems easy to prove that the bilinear map $$\mathcal{L}(u,v):=\int_M g^{ij}\partial_iu \partial_jv\mathop{d\mu_g}+\int_Muv\mathop{d\mu_g}$$ is bounded and coervice, from which the existence would follow immediately from the Lax-Milgram theorem, without using the compactness of $I_u$ nor the Fredholm's alternative. Am I doing something wrong here, or is it really that easy?

Comment: @b00nheT In that special case the associated bilinear form is in fact just the scalar product, so in this case you can in fact just refer to Lax-Milgram. Things are different as soon as you look at $\Delta u + du$ with general $d$, for example. I did not realize this nor check it since your question was in which way the Fredholm alternative applies. So this is what I tried to answer...(and, as you mentioned, you _are_ interested in other operators. Note, for example, that $\Delta$ has a nontrivial kernel on closed manifolds).

Comment: Okay! That's good news then. I thank you once more.
One last question (if you are kind enough to answer it I would really appreciate it): For the second operator, would you suggest analyzing it by means of the closed range theorem or by a similar technique to the one done in GT?

Comment: @b00nheT actually I'm not sure how exactly that operator is defined -- but it looks at if it is a rather common elliptic operator. Out of habit I'd try to use the technique in GT first.

Comment: Okay! Well, I'll try some approaches and see what happens. Thank you again for your help!